# Last modified Timestamp in MySQL

Tags: mysql

The default value of the column should be the one at the time of insertion and later when updation or deletion is done it should change in my sql

Comment: you haven't actually asked a question

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to set these properties on the field:

```
    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```